# Find difference between group of fields if the value of group 1 is higher than value of group 2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, difference

I have a table "Components" with the following fields

```
Person ID    Date_from      CompType       Value
000001       01/01/2003       A1            100
000001       01/01/2003       B1            200
000001       01/01/2003       C1            150
000001       01/01/2003       D1            180
000001       01/01/2003       E1            185
000001       01/01/2002       A1            125
000001       01/01/2002       B1            020
000001       01/01/2002       C1            130
000001       01/01/2002       D1            160
000001       01/01/2002       E1            105
000001       01/01/2001       A1            090
000001       01/01/2001       B1            200
000001       01/01/2001       C1            250
000001       01/01/2001       D1            160
000001       01/01/2001       E1            185
```

I need to find the difference between sum of (A1+B1+C1+D1) as S1 from the max DATE_FROM (01/01/2003) row and sum of (A1+B1+C1+D1) as S2 for the next date where S1-S2<>0

Similarly, I need to find the difference between sum of (A1+B1+C1+D1) as S2 from previous rows and sum of (A1+B1+C1+D1) as S3 for the next date where , S3-S2<>0

So , my output would be

```
ID           Date        Current Difference   Previous Difference
000001       01/01/2003          195             245
```

Also, if I do not find any difference in 01/01/2003 and 01/01/2002 data. The SQL should look into difference of 01/01/2003 and 01/01/2001 data sets.

Comment: If you don't want `E1`, why are you including it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to follow.  I think the following basically gets the data that you want -- but this returns three rows rather than 1.

```
select personId, date_from, 
       sum(case when comptype in ('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1') then value end) as current_sum,
       lag(sum(case when comptype in ('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1') then value end)) over (partition by personId order by min(date_from) as prev_sum,
       lag(sum(case when comptype in ('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1') then value end), 2) over (partition by personId order by min(date_from) as prev_sum,
from t
group by personId, date_from
order by personId, date_from desc;
```

In Oracle 12C, you can add `fetch first 1 row only` to get the top row.

Comment: I am unable to use any SQL functions such as Lag or Lead. The tool does not allow me to use such functions

Comment: @RohitPrasad . . . `lag()`/`lead()` has been in the pantheon of Oracle functions for a long time.  They are *definitely* part of Oracle 11:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm#SQLRF00652.

Comment: I understand that. However, Oracle Cloud Fusion SQL Builder Tool, does not allow us to write Lead or Lag functions. The error says "ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` function with aggregation and `abs()` at the main query as

```
with Components(Person_ID, Date_from, CompType, Value) as
(
 select '000001',date'2003-01-01','A1',100 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2003-01-01','B1',200 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2003-01-01','C1',150 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2003-01-01','D1',180 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2003-01-01','E1',185 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2002-01-01','A1',125 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2002-01-01','B1',20  from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2002-01-01','C1',130 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2002-01-01','D1',160 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2002-01-01','E1',105 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2001-01-01','A1',90  from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2001-01-01','B1',200 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2001-01-01','C1',250 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2001-01-01','D1',160 from dual union all
 select '000001',date'2001-01-01','E1',185 from dual
), t2 as
(
select Person_ID, Date_from, sum(Value) as sum1, 
       lag(sum(Value),1,0) over (order by Date_from) as sum2,
       lag(sum(Value),2,0) over (order by Date_from) as sum3
  from Components
 where CompType != 'E1' 
 group by Person_ID, date_from
)
select Person_ID, date_from, 
       abs(sum1-sum2) as "Current Difference",
       abs(sum2-sum3) as "Previous Difference" 
  from t2
 where sum1 * sum2 * sum3 > 0;

PERSON_ID   DATE_FROM   Current Difference  Previous Difference
000001      01.01.2003        195                  265
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/PWZR62689)</kbd>